# Laravel Model attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using a third party table which very annoyingly has name and surname fields. The first name goes into name and of course the surname goes into surname.

I want to concat these together in the model as I will need to use the full name many times so I added:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute() : Attribute
{
    return new Attribute(
        $this->name . ' ' . $this->surname
    );
}
```

and then added

```
 protected $appends = ['full_name'];
```

I thought this would always show my concat field but when I dd the table it is not there.

Comment: Which version of Laravel is this? In `10.x`, it's `return Attribute::make(...)`, not `return new Attribute()`: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: As I remember when `dd($user)`, you should see something like this `#appends...`

Comment: Or, `dd($user->toArray())` or `dd($user->toJson())` should show a field for the appended `full_name` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

To define an accessor for an Attribute in Laravel, you need to do it this way and remove the type-hint **Attribute** from the declaration or replace it with **string**.

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
   return $this->name . ' ' . $this->surname;
}
```

Comment: Incorrect; that is the old syntax. Compare: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor vs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: @TimLewis In that case, you need to instantiate it using Make method:  https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the documentation I linked to both you and the person who asked this question...

Answer (score -2):

You can create accessor method in your model.

```
public function getFullName()
{
    return $this->name.' '.$this->surname;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly the same as the other answer here, except you're missing `Attribute` in the method name, so this is even more incorrect...